# What it's wrong with this code in py using the facebook_business api?

Tags: python, facebook-business-sdk

I want to create an app that posts a video to facebook and gets the auto generated caption.

```
from facebook_business.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebook_business.adobjects.video import Video
from facebook_business.adobjects.videothumbnail import VideoThumbnail
from facebook_business.adobjects.videocaption import VideoCaption
import urllib.request
import os

pwd = os.getcwd()

# Replace with your own access token and page ID
my_access_token = "Mytoken"
my_page_id = 'My-page-id'

# Initialize the Facebook API
FacebookAdsApi.init(access_token=my_access_token)

# Upload the video to Facebook
video = Video(parent_id=my_page_id)
video[Video.Field.filepath] = pwd + "/tttttt.mp4"
video.remote_create()

# Wait for Facebook to process the video
video.api_get(fields=[Video.Field.id, Video.Field.status], params={
    'fields': ','.join([Video.Field.id, Video.Field.status]),
    'allow_upgraded_video': True
})
while video[Video.Field.status] != Video.Status.READY:
    print('Waiting for video processing...')
    video.api_get(fields=[Video.Field.status], params={
        'fields': ','.join([Video.Field.status]),
        'allow_upgraded_video': True
    })

# Generate auto captions for the video
video[Video.Field.caption] = Video.CaptionValue.AUTO_GENERATED
video.remote_update()

# Wait for Facebook to generate the captions
video.api_get(fields=[Video.Field.id, Video.Field.status, Video.Field.captions], params={
    'fields': ','.join([Video.Field.id, Video.Field.status, Video.Field.captions]),
    'allow_upgraded_video': True
})
while not video[Video.Field.captions]['data']:
    print('Waiting for caption generation...')
    video.api_get(fields=[Video.Field.captions], params={
        'fields': ','.join([Video.Field.captions]),
        'allow_upgraded_video': True
    })

# Download the SRT file to your computer
caption = VideoCaption(fbid=video[Video.Field.captions]['data'][0]['id'])
caption.api_get(fields=[VideoCaption.Field.caption_file_urls])
srt_url = caption[VideoCaption.Field.caption_file_urls][0]['url']
urllib.request.urlretrieve(srt_url, 'output.srt')
```

I installed the facebook api using pip but the lines:

```
from facebook_business.adobjects.video import Video
```

and

```
from facebook_business.adobjects.videocaption import VideoCaption
```

This lines are getting import problems:
1 - Import "facebook_business.adobjects.video" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports
2 - Import "facebook_business.adobjects.videocaption" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports

I try to reinstall and upgrade the api but didn't work.